# I am trying to make a ip pinger like the ones in cmd but it wont work

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, canvas

```
import os
from playsound import playsound
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x650')
c = Canvas(root, height=645, width=695, bg="orange")
s = c.create_rectangle(5, 5, 693, 200, fill="green")

def update():
    with open("C:\\Users\Wasif\Desktop\ipaddresses.txt") as file:
        dump = file.read()
        dump = dump.splitlines()

    for i in dump:
        ip = i.split()[1]
        host = i.split()[0]
        res = os.popen(f"ping {ip} -n 2").read()
        print(res)
        if "Request timed out" in res:
            playsound("C:\\Users\Wasif\Desktop\Alarm.mp3")
    x = res
    t = c.create_text(286, 100, fill="black", font="Times 20 italic bold", text=x)
    root.after(1000, update)  # run itself again after 1000 ms

c.pack()
update()
root.mainloop()
```

i want it to make an alarm if there are packet losses and to show the pinging on screen but it wont budge. after this works i will add a latency checker, my problem is with the canvas. is there a way to make this an exe with just the alarm or do i have to it it with canvas.

Comment: `playsound ` is probably incompatible with `tkinter`. You might be able to workaround that by creating a thread that played the alarm sound (as long as nothing in it interacted with the GUI).

Comment: @martineau I think `playsound()` has a keyword argument `block` which if set to False should not interfere with mainloop (not entirely sure what it does but it might use a thread or sth already): `playsound('path/to/file', block=False)`, but actually I would suggest putting the whole `update` function in its own separate thread because other methods might block the mainloop too at least for some time (reading file, usimg that loop, `os.popen` (not sure about this since it may start a new process similarly to `subprocess.Popen`))

Comment: @Matiiss:  I agree that running the whole `update()` function in a separate thread is probably be a good idea. What `playsound` does when `block=False` depends on the OS — but it definitely sounds worth trying. `os.popen` opens a separate process, which ought to prevent it from interfering with `mainloop()`. Whether the file reading is a problem would of course depend on the size of the file (which also affects how long the following `for` loop takes to process them all).

Comment: @martineau I guess I didn't mention but as far as I know, calling tkinter methods from other threads may cause it to crash, so not exactly the WHOLE update function but the parts that are not related to tkinter, then OP could use queues and after scripts to update those Widgets in the same thread, in that case might as well use another process (seems not needed for the amount of data processing) and then use queues and after scripts for updating just then there would be no thread to consume the resources of the process that runs the already slow tkinter

Comment: @Matiiss: Yes, only one thread can control the GUI in a multithreaded application using tkinter — so `update()` couldn't call the canvas `create_text()`  method like that. The workaround is usually to put information in a `Queue` which the tkinter thread periodically checks and updates the GUI with as needed.